# Unresponsive Screen

Tags: screen, touchscreen, home-screen

How do I deal with a frozen or unresponsive screen on my Android phone? I have tried restarting the phone multiple times, but the issue persists.

Comment: There are multiple's reason that cause this Problem Please be specfic